# how to share data to all view in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

i dont find any answer to share data to all view in codeigniter 4

anybody can share me how to share data to all view in codeigniter 4.

i am using basecontroller to share data, but i think it not perfect. in laravel have file appserviceprovider, but in codeigniter i dont have any solution to solve it

in my basecontroller
`

```
$cateModel = new \App\Models\CateModel();
$data2['cate'] = $cateModel->findAll();
$pageModel = new PageModel();
$data2['page_home'] = $pageModel->where('page_status', 1)->first();
$data2['link_page'] = $pageModel->where('page_status !=', 1)->find();
// dd($data['link_page']);

return view('front_end/canvas_site/layout', $data2).view('admin/admin-layout', $dataLogin);
```

so i wonder ask that anybody can help me?

thank alot

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify your question further.

If it is temporary data related to users (language, login, etc.) then you should look for the SESSION mechanism. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

If you want to perform processing on data (as it seems to be the case in your example), then you could use the HELPER feature among others. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html